# Get the next 6 any numbers after specific two numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get from string the numbers 24 or 99 with the next six any numbers. For example, imagine the followed string:

```
anytext 24 824 750 anytext 99 659 440 anytext 24 234 423 24743534 anytext
```

What I what to get is:

```
24824750 99659440 24234423 24743534
```

Comment: What is the environment? You will have to use 2 steps here: remove spaces, get the matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Javascript, Thank you.

Comment: Great, have you had any luck so far? Could you share your code?

Comment: I can't try now, I'll try in two hours and I'll share my tries, if I don't get any answer until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var r=/(24|99)(\s*[0-9]){6}/g;
var s='anytext 24 824 750 anytext 99 659 440 anytext 24 234 423 24743534 anytext';
var m;
while(true) {
    m = r.exec(s);
    if(!m) break;
    console.log(m[0].replace(/\s/g,''));
}
```

You can change `\s` to space if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it (ES6 code):

```js
var txt = 'anytext 24 824 750 anytext 99 659 440 anytext 24 234 423 24743534 anytext';

var res = txt.match(/(24|99)(\s*\d){6}/g).map( m => m.replace(/\s+/g, '') );

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows

```js
var str = "anytext 24 824 750 anytext 99 659 440 anytext 24 234 423 24743534 anytext",
 result = str.replace(/\s+/g,"")
             .match(/(?:24|99)\d{6}/g);
console.log(result);
```